# Is the number of electrons in the universe always the same?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, conservation-laws, standard-model

My teacher just said the number of electrons in the universe always stays the same, that's not how I understood weak force interactions and electron capture. Is there some rule that states that the number of electrons will always be the same in the universe, is the number of particles in the electron quantum field somehow preserved, or is it variable?

Comment: As it has been Pointed out by Micheal, Nuclear Beta Decay, Pair Production Reactions Do Exist and They Result in Emitted Positrons or Electrons. As a Result, The Number of Electrons are Not Constant. However. In all cases, The Conservation of Mass holds True. Even when Electrons are Emitted in Beta Decay, The Mass of Particles that Exist in the Universe Remains a Constant **As Per Our Current Understanding of the World**

Comment: Are electrons inside a blackhole still counted?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there was a specific rule saying either A: The number of electrons and/or other particles in the universe is always the same, or B: There are short violations of this but after a certain amount of time the quantum field balances back to having the same amount of electrons.

Comment: I haven't heard about such rule, just total charge of universe must be conserved and as long as I know it is about zero. But separately, negative and positive charge densities can vary over time.

Comment: Number of electrons minus number of positrons is closer to being conserved, but it's still not the full electron lepton number.

Comment: @DevNotTaken "The Mass of Particles that Exist in the Universe Remains a Constant " is not a correct statement . Mass is the length of the four vector describing individual particles and also the sum of  four vectors in an ensemble.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: @DevNotTaken This is unrelated to the question, but why are you capitalizing so many random words? I see people do this from time to time and I always want to know the reasoning behind it, but no one has yet given an answer.

Comment: Hydrogen fusion in stars converts some protons to neutrons, releasing positrons, which annihilate with electrons. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/563975/123208 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43908/16685 for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you already noticed there are processes
of the weak interaction which do change the number of electrons.

- [$\beta^-$ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2%E2%88%92_decay): $n \to p + e^- +\bar{\nu}_e$
- [$\beta^+$ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay): $p \to n + e^+ + \nu_e$
- [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Electron_capture_(K-capture)): $p + e^- \to n + \nu_e$
- [Muon decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#Muon_decay): $\mu^- \to e^- + \bar{\nu}_e + \nu_\mu$
- [Tau decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_(particle)#Tau_decay): $\tau^- \to e^- + \bar{\nu}_e + \nu_\tau$

And even the electromagnetic interaction can create or destroy electrons.

- [electron-positron annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation): $e^- + e^+ \to \gamma + \gamma$
- [electron-positron production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron): $\gamma + \text{nucleus} \to e^- + e^+ + \text{nucleus}$

So the number of electrons is certainly not conserved.
But the [number of leptons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number) is conserved, if you count leptons
($e^-, \mu^-, \tau^-, \nu_e, \nu_\mu, \nu_\tau$) as positive
and anti-leptons ($e^+, \mu^+, \tau^+, \bar\nu_e, \bar\nu_\mu, \bar\nu_\tau$)
as negative.

Comment: The number of leptons is not conserved either. In the Standard Model with massless neutrinos only a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ subgroup of lepton number is conserved. At zero temperature the violation of $U(1)_L$ is very small, but in the early universe there is significant violation by sphalerons. 
But also if neutrinos have Majorana masses, then lepton number is not conserved. We do not know yet if neutrinos are Majorana or Dirac.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the number of electrons that are conserved but the number of leptons. There is a caveat though, there are virtual processes where we have virtual leptons. Including these shows that the number of leptons is in fact not conserved. But generally, when we say leptons we exclude virtal leptons. So lepton number is indeed conserved.

Comment: Well, "virtual particles" (meaning internal lines in Feynman diagrams) aren't particles, but a computational tool for perturbative calculations, and also lepton number is conserved at each vertex in such diagrams, so the numer of leptons wold still be conserved if virtaul particles were counted.

Comment: @Toffomat: That some people choose to think of virtual particles as "a computational tool" I think arises from a very conservative and formalist outlook. I prefer to with Feynman and call them virtual particles. I stand corrected about virtual Lepton number though - its some time since I looked at my particle physics texts.

Comment: Well, they are generaly called virtual particles, but they're still computational tools to expand spome intermediat field configurations. (Maybe that's what Feynman meant with virtual.) That's why there are no virtual particles in nonperturbative fields such as low-energy QCD, lattice field theory, CFT, instantons etc.

Comment: @Toffomat: I think you are pushing your perspective on physicists who don't accept your perspective. When Feynman used the term "virtual particle", he meant it. The perspective you are using is called formalist. Can you provide a reference to show that Feynman thought virtual particles as merely a calculational device  in QED?

Comment: I don't know why Feynman chose the name "virtual" particles (or indeed if it was his naming choice), and I don't really care. I think there is no doubt that the name stuck, and neither that they (indeed the whole machinery of Feynman diagrams) are computational tools to compute amplitudes (see e.g. https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/ for a nice discussion). It's not clear to me in what way this would be "formalist", really. What else should be the perspective on perturbative calculations?

Comment: @Toffomat: Formalist means that no ontological meaning is given to symbols, since you do not ascribe ontological substance to virtual particles ergo your perspective is formalist. I've come across Strassler's article - but I don't happen to agree with it. The point I'm making is that very good physicists also disagree with your view and its not merely my opinion. Lets agree to disagree on this as we are just going round in circles here.

Comment: Well, I guess that as long as you don't really say what you think yirtual particles are, we are unlikely to progress much.